# Multiple directories: Powershell equivalent of "mkdir dir{1..9}"?

Tags: linux, powershell, command-line-arguments, mkdir

What is the syntax to create multiple directories with PowerShells md (or mkdir, New-Item...) equivalent to the 'nix command `mkdir ch{1..9}` i.e.

```
~/parent_dir/  
ch1/  
ch2/  
ch3/  
ch4/  
ch5/  
ch6/  
ch7/  
ch8/  
ch9/
```

I've looked in the man pages and get-help for examples, but I do not know the syntax for PowerShell to do such a simple thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### What is the syntax to create multiple directories with PowerShell

Use the following command:

```
0..9 | foreach $_{ New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $("ch" + $_) }
```

**How it works:**

- `0..9` the [range operator](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) `..` generates the sequence of numbers 0, 1, ... 9
- the numbers are [pipelined](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-pipeline.html) `|` to the next command
- `foreach` [loops](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html) (through each number in turn)
- `{ ... }` is a [script block](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-scriptblock.html)
- `New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $("ch" + $_)` [creates](http://ss64.com/ps/new-item.html) the directories
- `$_` is an [automatic variable](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html) that represents the current object in the pipeline (the number)

Example:

```
> 0..9 | foreach $_{ New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $("ch" + $_) }


    Directory: F:\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch0
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch1
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch2
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch3
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch4
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch5
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch6
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch7
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch8
d-----       25/09/2016     14:57                ch9
```

Comment: There is nothing less verbose than entering the following: `1..9 | % $_{ md -name $("ch" + $_) }` ?

Comment: I think so. But I'm no PowerShell expert.

Comment: Ha - me neither! ...as a follow up to this, if the parent dir were full of files prepended with corresponding ch#s, would `1..9 | % $_{ mv ch$_.* ch$_ }` put all the ch#.ext files in the corresponding ch#/ directories?

Comment: It looks OK, but I suggest you try it and see :)

Comment: Oh, of course, I've been trying various incatations to no avail :\

Comment: a-HA - got it: `1..9 | % $_{ mv ch$_*.* ch$_ }` :^D

Comment: YaY - `git add` worked: `1..9 | % $_{ git add $("ch" + $_) }` ...but this: `1..9 | % $_{ git commit -m $("ch" + $_) }` will take some thinking upon... Thanks again, IRL, you have a cup of coffee on me anytime!

Comment: I've added some more explanation to the answer (how it works).

Comment: Very useful explanation. In the continuing case of taking these new directories and moved files to a github repository, would this long piping add and commit files so each ch# dir and files have a corresponding ch# update comment? `1..9 | % $_{ git add $("ch" + $_) } | % $_{ git commit -m $("ch" + $_) }`

Comment: I don't know. I'm still a PowerShell beginner. I had to look things up to answer your question ;)

Comment: K - if i find out how, I'll post a solution, thx!!!

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy Couple things. You should try running the `git add` and see what it returns - keep in mind that `$_` inside a foreach is only each individual array entry of the last pipeline item (which means the `commit` step in your example won't get raw numbers, so adding `ch` again is probably wrong). Also, in your example, the commits would only(?) run after all adds are done, which means the first commit would get everything... Alternatively, you could use multiple statements (separated by `;`) inside a single foreach step.

Comment: Thanks - your insights are very helpful and yes - everything got "ch1" as an update comment.

Comment: I'll contribute a slightly more concise alternative: 1..9 | mkdir -Name { "ch$_" }

Answer (score 23):

You don't need to invoke mkdir multiple times, because `New-Item` can take an array of paths. For example:

```
mkdir $(1..9 | %{"ch$_"})
```

@DavidPostill has explained most of the concepts in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1128116/117590). This also takes advantage of [string interpolation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/) instead of performing an explicit concatenation. Additionally, the `%` shorthand is used instead of `ForEach-Object`, but has the same meaning.

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an easy way to interpolate a string into an array of strings as in bash.

Comment: Oh. A much simpler solution. Should I delete my beginners effort?

Comment: @DavidPostill You've explained in far more detail than I. This might be more of an addendum to your answer :P

Comment: @DavidPostill please don't delete it - your explanation is very useful

Comment: Bob, excellent point about only invoking mkdir once with this syntax.

Comment: Maximally golfed version: `md(0..9|%{"ch$_"})`

Comment: @BenN s/golf/obfuscat/ :) I need a translator for that. Is there something that translates back and forth?

Comment: @DavidPostill `md` is a standard alias for `mkdir`, which is a PowerShell function. `%`, as Bob mentioned, is a standard alias for `ForEach-Object`. Double-quoted strings interpolate  variables, so `"ch$_"` is equivalent to `'ch' + $_`. You can look up an alias by running `Get-Command` (`gcm`) on it.

Comment: Bob and @BenN , with this syntax, how to move corresponding ch#.files into ch#/ directories? This (and similar incantations) are failing: `mv $( 1..9 | %{ "ch$_*.*" } { "ch$_" } )`

Comment: Ahh... got it: `mv $( 1..9 | %{ "ch$_*.* ch$_" } )`

Comment: Good point! Any idea how to pipe git add and commit commands to these folders so each corresponding set has their update comments with corresponding #s?

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy ...are you sure that works? I don't think move can take multiple destinations at a time, so you'll have to go with a pipeline as in David's answer for a move. Do keep in mind that "ch1*.*" will catch "ch11.txt" as well...

Comment: Bob, whoops - you are correct, sir! My bad!

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy Something like: `1..9 | %{"ch$_"} | %{git add "$_"; git commit -m "$_"}` or `1..9 | %{$name = "ch$_"; git add "$name"; git commit -m "$name"}`. These comments are getting a bit long now, so if you have further questions - please ask them as questions, or maybe drop into chat.

Answer (score 2):

Create multiple directories underneath the current directory:

```
mkdir ('abc','def','jkl')
```

The above is a short-hand version of the following.  Notice the at-sign included in front of the array of strings and the use of named parameters:

```
mkdir -Path @('abc','def','jkl')
```

And if you want to go all the way, the full native command would be:

```
New-Item -Path @('abc','def','jkl') -ItemType Directory
```

When using the PowerShell command-line, I use the short version.

When writing a script, especially one for others (who might be new to PowerShell), I tend to write the full native command.

Choose whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use for loop version as it is easy to remember and can be applied to many situations. Even it can be used for multiple command.

For an equivalent of this bash command:

> for i in {1..9}; do
>   mkdir ch$i
>   done

...in PowerShell use:

```
for($i=1;
$i -le 10;
$i++)
{md ch$i}
```

Comment: mamum, could you clarify - I get an error when I run your code from the PowerShell command line, or, as a ps1 script: `Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.` This command: `foreach ($i in 1..9) {md ch$i}` gets me numbered "ch"apter directories, but I don't understand your "for...;do...done" loop.

Comment: The for loop I used here is for bash shell (/bin/sh). I always change my shell to bash as I am used to this shell. For ps, you have to use different syntax for for loop (please see the attached link http://ss64.com/ps/for.html)

Comment: PowerShell: `for($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++){md ch$i}` thanks mamun, but I'm not yet "Bourne again..." ;) (nor do I know C++, but I think I sorta understand what "$i-le" (if less than or equal to?) and "$i++" (~"i+=1"?) mean and are doing in the command...

Comment: Yes, the argument ca be read as for (initialize i from 1; as long as i less than or equal to 1; increase i by 1){do stuff iteratively}