# Multiple directories padded with leading zeros from a single call to mkdir in PowerShell?

Tags: linux, command-line, powershell, mkdir

How to make multiple directories with padded zeros from a single call to `md` (`mkdir`, `New-Item`)? From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531978/create-folders-with-leading-zeroes-in-powershell), I see that I can use this command to pad regular directory names with trailing numbers:

`0..10 | % { "dir_name{0:000}" -f $_ } | % { New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $_ }`

~/directory/
dir_name000
dir_name001
dir_name002
dir_name003
dir_name004
dir_name005
dir_name006
dir_name007
dir_name008
dir_name009
dir_name010

...but is there a less verbose way with a single call to `md`?

Thanks to all the helpful input on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1128113/multiple-directories-powershell-equivalent-of-mkdir-dir1-9) about finding a PowerShell equivalent to the 'nix command: `mkdir dir_name{1..9}` I see how this command:

`0..10 | foreach $_{ New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $("dir_name" + $_) }`

...can be done like this:

`mkdir $(0..10 | %{"dir_name$_"})`

...but how would I slug in the number padding into this syntax? Thank you!

Comment: Aha! After many incantations, I figured out a solution: `md -Name $_ $(0..10 | % { "dir_name{0:000}" -f $_ } )` I am having trouble wrapping my head around piping syntax and PowerShell mojo... Any resource suggestions?

Comment: this looks promising: [Effective Windows PowerShell: The Free eBook](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/effective-windows-powershell-the-free-ebook/)

Comment: `0..10 | % { "dir_name{0:000}" -f $_ } | % { New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $_ > $null}` note that the [output is `>` directed](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) to NULL device `$null`. Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/5263780/3439404 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`md -Name $_ $(0..10 | % { "dir_name{0:000}" -f $_ } )`

~/directory/
dir_name000
dir_name001
dir_name002
...
dir_name008
dir_name009
dir_name010

Comment: You should mark this as the answer.

Comment: @root, thanks - I will as soon as the waiting period is over. Pls vote me up if you think the question or answer are useful :)